# HS_PRMS_8 sku in azurerm_mssql_database gives the error This is not a valid sku name

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I am not able to use any of premium series azure ms sql sku names in terraform `azurerm_mssql_database` module. It gives an error saying SKU name is not valid. Other SKUs such as `HS_Gen5_4 works` fine.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "module_sqldatabase" {
  name           = var.sqlserverdatabase_name
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.module_sqlserver.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  max_size_gb    = 2
  sku_name       = "HS_PRMS_8"
  tags = local.common_tags  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `azurerm_mssql_database` resource in Terraform does not support the SKU `HS_PRMS_8`. However, you can utilize the Azure Terraform resource `azapi_resource` as an alternative. I attempted to create an MSSQL database with the SKU `HS_PRMS_8` using the provided code, and the results were as expected.

```json
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
  client_id                   = ""
  client_secret               = ""
  tenant_id                   = ""
  subscription_id             = ""
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  
  }

resource "azapi_resource" "sqldbvjytf" {
  type = "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview"
  name = "sqldbvjytf"
  location = "East US"
  parent_id = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/v-goonav-mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsqlservervjy"
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      collation = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    }
    sku = {
      capacity = 8
      family = "PRMS"
      name = "HS_PRMS"
      tier = "Hyperscale"
    }
  })
}
```

Below is the ouptut when I executed `terraform apply` command to deploy and also verified in azure portal.
[terraform plan output](https://i.imgur.com/SmJHtJq.png)
https://i.imgur.com/1Ay8RFy.png

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2022-05-01-preview/servers/databases?pivots=deployment-language-terraform